# What will you call this part in a monitor stand?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

I am going to talk a topic about monitor stand in English with native English speakers, I will specifically talk about this part:
[image]
[image]

What is the best word I can use for the part that will definitely let a native English speaker know what I am talking about?

feet, legs? or?

Comment: Best to use a generic term. I would call them _supports._

Comment: I think *legs* is OK, but *supports* will definitely be understood too.

Answer (score 1):

Tables have legs. The little trays for eating breakfast in bed have folding legs. I'd say that **legs** is a good choice.

Though **supports** would be understood I don't think that is quite as good as supports are often separate from the thing they support.